# R: stable method for transforming selected list columns to numeric

Tags: r, list, dataframe, multiple-columns, numeric

I have a list that looks like:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~City,   ~State, ~Year,  ~Temp,
"", "", "Year", "Overall temperature, by now",
"Aberdeen", "", "2022", "18.73",
"Aberdeen", "", "2021", "17.79",
"Aberdeen", "", "2020", "-",
"Aberdeen", "", "2019", "16.43",
"Aberdeen", "", "2018", "-",
"Aberdeen", "", "2017", "17.84",
"Aberdeen", "", "2016", "17.47",
"Aberdeen", "", "2015", "25.84",
"Aberdeen", "", "2014", "26.8",
"Aberdeen", "", "2013", "22.73",
"Aberdeen", "", "2012", "23.08",
"Aalborg",  "P1",   "Year", "Temp, measurement",
"Aalborg",  "P1",   "2022", "-",
"Aalborg",  "P1",   "2021", "20.05")
```

Or, the same data for visual representation:
[image]

I need to turn the last two columns to numeric.
In addition, it would be good to turn this list to dataframe (please, consider a method :)

It is a small sample of a big dataset.

Here is what doesn't work (although I used these methods for working with less complicated lists):

```
df1[, 3] <- as.numeric(df1[, 3]) #for sure, it is a list
# Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
as.numeric(unlist(df1[[3]])) 
# Error: (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
df1[, 3:4] <- sapply(df1, as.numeric)
# Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) :  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df1[[3]]))) 
# Error: (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
df1$Year <- lapply(df1$Year, as.numeric)
# Error in lapply(df1$Year, as.numeric) :  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1) #Working with a dataframe would be easier :)
typeof(df1)
# [1] "list"

as.numeric(df1[1, 3]) #If that would work - we could use loop to change element by element into numeric 
# Error: (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
typeof(df1)
# [1] "list"
```

I don't care about the disappeared text data in the numeric columns after the transformation (these data are useless).

Update: we found that methods to work with lists are not robust - running some modern libraries deprecate the work of vital functions. But I can't find which libraries make solutions not working :( Can you, please, help.

Libraries I often use:
"plyr", "dplyr", "data.table","tidyverse","magrittr", "tidyr", "reshape2", "expss", "janitor",
"dplyr", "ggplot2", "purrr", "GGally", "cluster", "readxl", "writexl", "psych",
"knitr", "ExPanDaR", "kableExtra", "plm", "sampleSelection", "nnet", "ggmap", "scales",
"RPostgreSQL","readr","lubridate","seasonal","stargazer","merTools","RColorBrewer","colorRamps", "nycflights13", "scales", "zoo", "stringr",
"maps", "mapdata", "gtrendsR", "cdlTools", "usmap", "rnaturalearth", "WDI", "tigris", "ggrepel", "rworldmap", "gapminder"
System coding:
Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_ALL','en_US.UTF-8')

Answer (score 1):

It is a `tibble`, so `[,` would still return a tibble with single column as `drop = FALSE` by default when compared to `data.frame`.  Instead use either `$` or `[[` to extract as vector.  For multiple columns, use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `sapply` can return a `matrix`

```
df1[3:4] <- lapply(df1[3:4], as.numeric)
```

-output

```
> str(df1)
tibble [15 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ City : chr [1:15] "" "Aberdeen" "Aberdeen" "Aberdeen" ...
 $ State: chr [1:15] "" "" "" "" ...
 $ Year : num [1:15] NA 2022 2021 2020 2019 ...
 $ Temp : num [1:15] NA 18.7 17.8 NA 16.4 ...
> df1
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   City       State  Year  Temp
   <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ""         ""       NA  NA  
 2 "Aberdeen" ""     2022  18.7
 3 "Aberdeen" ""     2021  17.8
 4 "Aberdeen" ""     2020  NA  
 5 "Aberdeen" ""     2019  16.4
 6 "Aberdeen" ""     2018  NA  
 7 "Aberdeen" ""     2017  17.8
 8 "Aberdeen" ""     2016  17.5
 9 "Aberdeen" ""     2015  25.8
10 "Aberdeen" ""     2014  26.8
11 "Aberdeen" ""     2013  22.7
12 "Aberdeen" ""     2012  23.1
13 "Aalborg"  "P1"     NA  NA  
14 "Aalborg"  "P1"   2022  NA  
15 "Aalborg"  "P1"   2021  20.0
```

For single column

```
> class(df1[,3])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(df1[[3]])
[1] "numeric"
```

---

As the input is tibble, we can use `dplyr` methods

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(3:4, as.numeric))
```

Comment: Dear Akrun! Thanks for solution. But, it is not so easy, especially in the up-to-date libraries: df1[3:4] <- lapply(df1[3:4], as.numeric)
Error in lapply(df1[3:4], as.numeric) : 
  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: df1 <- df1 %>%
+     mutate(across(3:4, as.numeric))
Error: (converted from warning) Problem while computing `..1 = across(3:4, as.numeric)`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev It is a warning message because you have some characters `""` got converted to NA

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev error and wwarning is different.

Comment: No, it is not anymore. It now is an error. It was a warning in the former versions of packages. Having this Error functions do not work in R :(

Comment: Here is the screenshot (saved @ google drive): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgBlhoaGGQ2O4KZkzHKtd_l5PxeoLY2Q/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev I don't get any error though.  Maybe you are trying this on the changed data with your code

Comment: I am doing it with the same data. Please, have a look at the screenshot above. There is the data input and the reply of R. The last phrase of the Error is "eaten" by the screenshot. So it was: Error: (converted from warning) Problem while computing `..1 = across(3:4, as.numeric)`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev I posted the output I got

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev I run it on the same data you showed.

Comment: Me too. But I have a newly installed R and all packages (2 days ago). So, here is my input-ouput (screenshot; there is an error [not warning] and it doesn't modify the data as seen from the screenshot): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n6y7q4KvkZaV9AWRgYOGnEfknow3Rglb/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev it is a bit strange about the error. The base R method should have worked fine.  I am using `R 4.2.2` on a mac

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev can you try it on a fresh R session

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev i have to leave now.  So will check the message later

Comment: Ok, thanks. I run the test on a clean R - it is some package conflict (which is good, it means the R environment works). But I can't find which one to make the method robust of no matter what libraries to run :)

Comment: I found that methods to work with lists are not robust. Can you, please, help to make your solution fully robust without depending on what libraries are used in the system, please :)

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev Here, I used only `dplyr`.  if you have loaded other packages or your env got corrupted.  The first soluiton is `base R`, so it shouldn't have an effect though

Answer (score 1):

First remove all words in `Year` and `Temp` then convert them to the apropriate class `integer` for `Year` and `double` for `Temp`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df1 %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!grepl("^[A-Z]", Year), 
         !grepl("^[A-Z]", Temp)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Year = readr::parse_integer(Year),
         Temp = readr::parse_number(Temp))

# A tibble: 13 × 4
   City     State  Year  Temp
   <chr>    <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1 Aberdeen ""     2022  18.7
 2 Aberdeen ""     2021  17.8
 3 Aberdeen ""     2020  NA  
 4 Aberdeen ""     2019  16.4
 5 Aberdeen ""     2018  NA  
 6 Aberdeen ""     2017  17.8
 7 Aberdeen ""     2016  17.5
 8 Aberdeen ""     2015  25.8
 9 Aberdeen ""     2014  26.8
10 Aberdeen ""     2013  22.7
11 Aberdeen ""     2012  23.1
12 Aalborg  "P1"   2022  NA  
13 Aalborg  "P1"   2021  20.0
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. But there is a replicability problem:  df1 %>% 
+   filter(!grepl("^[A-Z]", Year), 
+          !grepl("^[A-Z]", Temp)) %>% 
+   mutate(Year = parse_integer(Year),
+          Temp = parse_number(Temp))
Error: (converted from warning) Problem while computing `Temp = parse_number(Temp)`.
ℹ 3 parsing failures. row col expected actual 3 -- a number - 5 -- a number -
  12 -- a number -

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev as you can see, the code worked well in the example data, therefore it is not a code problem, maybe your example is not representative of your problem and that's why it is not working as you expected.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run it on a "fresh" R session and it worked. There is some conflict with the libraries I often use (to work with the lists), and I can't find which and what to do to make the solution fully robust. Can you, please, help :)

Comment: You can avoid these conflicts by calling each functions directly from the environmet they belong to, for example `dplyr::filter`, `dplyr::mutate`, see my edit. Maybe the problem is with `filter` function.